# After upgrading from 22.04 to 22.10 keyboard,mouse works only in Menu bar and dock and cannot start terminal

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, mouse, 22.10

I am already running 22.04 when I try to upgrade to 22.10 but when I boot my cursor is only active in the dock and menu bar. I can start some programs but cursor disappears and keyboard will not work. Cannot start terminal. What could be the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: I did the upgrade to 22.10 which was the next available upgrade as suggested and the same things happened.